# API 30 - Copying non media files from external storage to internal storage

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-external-storage, android-internal-storage

Does anyone have experience with copying a `.TXT` file in `Android 11 - API 30` from external storage to the app directory (internal storage), specifically from the `Download` folder to `storage/emulated/0/Android/data/[PACKAGE_NAME]/files/MyDir` but without usage `permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. If there is a possibility, can you give a concrete example, thank you.

Copy into Download folder

```
recovery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // copy iz int memo u download
            try {
                File sdcard = getBaseContext().getExternalFilesDir(null);
                appRecovery(
                        new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath()),
                        new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS))));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // bris check
            clearAppData();

        }
    });
```

Copy from Download folder

```
    restore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // copy
            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                if (SDK_INT >= 23) {
                    if (checkPermission()) {
                        try {
                            File sdcardDic = getBaseContext().getExternalFilesDir(null);
                            File dirDic = new File(sdcardDic.getAbsolutePath() + "/Text/");
                            dirDic.mkdir();
                            File fileDic = new File(dirDic, "MyTextFile.html");
                            Toasty.success(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.restore_toasty_text), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            FileOutputStream dic = null;
                            try {
                                dic = new FileOutputStream(fileDic);
                                dic.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            File sdcardAudio = getBaseContext().getExternalFilesDir(null);
                            File dirAudio = new File(sdcardAudio.getAbsolutePath() + "/Audio/");
                            dirAudio.mkdir();
                            File fileAudio = new File(dirAudio, "Audio.mp3");
                            FileOutputStream audio = null;
                            try {
                                audio = new FileOutputStream(fileAudio);
                                audio.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            // copy
                            File sdcard = getBaseContext().getExternalFilesDir(null);
                            File dir = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath());
                            appRecovery(new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS))),
                                    new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // brise sadrzaj
                        File dirHtml = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/" + "/Text/" );
                        if (dirHtml.isDirectory()) {
                            String[] children = dirHtml.list();
                            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                                new File(dirHtml, children[i]).delete();
                            }
                        }

                        File dirMp3 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/" + "/Audio/" );
                        if (dirMp3.isDirectory()) {
                            String[] children = dirMp3.list();
                            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                                new File(dirMp3, children[i]).delete();
                            }
                        }

                    } else {
                        requestPermission();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

}

public void appRecovery(File sourceLocation, File targetLocation)
        throws IOException {

    if (sourceLocation.isDirectory()) {
        if (!targetLocation.exists()) {
            targetLocation.mkdir();
        }

        String[] children = sourceLocation.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceLocation.listFiles().length; i++) {

            appRecovery(new File(sourceLocation, children[i]),
                    new File(targetLocation, children[i]));
        }
    } else {

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetLocation);

        // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: If your app did not download the content to `Download/` itself, it will have no access to that content, unless you use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument` and the user chooses that content.

Comment: Thanks, but, in my case, by clicking the Recovery, I make a backup copy of the .TXT file from int. storage in the Download, I need to click the Restore to return the same file from Download to the int. storage.

Comment: If you can copy to then you can also copy from. What is the problem? What is the difference?

Comment: "I need to click the Restore to return the same file from Download to the int. storage" -- then use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`. You will get a `Uri` to the content that the user wants restored. Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to read in that content, verify that it meets your expectations, and do something with it.

Comment: You should post the code with which you copied to Download folder. Then we will tell you again that you can use the same code to copy the file back. It is pretty unclear which problem you have.

Comment: I posted the code you asked for in my post, please help, thanks

Comment: @blackapps did you look at the code with which I copy in Download?

Comment: `appRecovery(
                        new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath()),
                        new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS))));
            }` If that copies to the Download folder then just swapping the parameters will copy from that folder. Further i did not look at the appRecovery() code because as said before: if your code can copy to then it can also copy from. Just by exchanging source and destination. And why dont you name that function copyFile()?

Comment: It's also confusing, because it copies from internal storage to Download, but from Download it doesn't copy to internal storage, I repeat, it copies .mp3, but it doesn't copy .html

Comment: I emphasize, when I put the permission `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` everything works, but I have a problem because the Play console rejected my app because of this permission - by this I mean Android 11 as a problem!

Comment: What you say about extensions makes no sense. Neither that about manage external storage.

Comment: ok, but what is the problem, do you see the solution or not???

Comment: If it doesn't make sense, how can it work when I add this permission, can you explain to me???

Comment: Terrible. You are doing much more in your code then you told us. Please remove the listings and recursions. Post the code for one copyFile(source, destination) function and call it first with copyFile(path1, path2) and then for back copyFile(path2, path1). Only if you see that you can handle one file you can go for a lot of files. What you do in your code now you did not tell and it takes too much time to find out. So please one function that you call twice.

Comment: Ti prijatelju nemas tri čuke, hvala